# css scaled background image

Tags: html, image, scale

i can get images scaled to fill the window when they are the content, like so:
(without any html5 or div)

```
  <style type="text/css">
img {
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0px;
}
  </style>
```

and

```
<img src="wacard.png" alt="original image" title="">
```

but

this fails (both "html, body" and just "body")

```
  <style type="text/css">
body {
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0px;
}
  </style>
```

and

```
<body
 style="background-image: url(wacard.png);">
</body>
```

as picked up picked up from here: [Resize HTML5 canvas to fit window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664785/html5-canvas-resize-to-fit-window/3078427#3078427) but as far as i understand, that must have some more fancy code than i know of, going on, ... or i'm doing something wrong...

how can i get background images to scale?
(ideally, without javascript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a great tutorial with several solutions:
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/
Complete with demos and the step by step coding process.

The HTML5 way mentioned is:

```
html {
        background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
}
```

There is an ie fix mentioned in the article.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to create a full page re-sizable background. If so, follow the instructions here => http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

Also consider for further review and options, as in my case, the value of the

```
background-position:
```

setting options...

http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

and also

```
background-origin:
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-origin

that accompany the backbackground-image CSS style setting.

Answer (score 0):

afaict, with a background image added

e.g. `background: url(back.jpg) fixed;`

all that's needed to make it scale, is

```
background-size: cover;
```

less is more.  ;)

Comment: added this answer for expedience and brevity, sparing my dyslexic beffuddlement and extra editting-out of the stuff i find supperfluous in jackreichert's good answer, every time i come back here to remind me over the years.