# Make resizeable handle visible on a canvas with specified dimentions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-ui

I'm dynamically creating a canvas element with a random width and height.

```
<div class="randBox">
    <canvas width="250px" height="100px" id="box"></canvas> 
    <!--width and height of the canvas is dynamic. I've used a fixed size for this example.-->
</div>
```

When I use the jquery resizable handle

```
jQuery('#box').resizable({
    handles: 'se'
});
```

css:

```
#box{
    background-color: red;
}

.ui-resizable-se{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 10px !important;
    height: 10px !important;
    bottom: 0px !important; /* E.g.: I want this at -15px */
    right: -5px !important; /* E.g.: I want this at -15px */
    display: block !important;
}
```

The resizable handle is hidden. Basically it looks like the handles are cropped to the canvas size.

How do I make the resizeable handle completely visible?

[**Example Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ceyzbjwd/1/)

Comment: **[The answers here might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368477/dynamically-resize-canvas-window-with-javascript-jquery)** and **[This link too](http://htmlcheats.com/html/resize-the-html5-canvas-dyamically/)**

Comment: Make sure that jquery-ui.css is loaded correctly (look for the errors in inspect element). You should add <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"> in the head tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not exactly a best practice, it should work for this example. The `.ui-wrapper` element has some CSS written directly onto it by the jQuery UI library, which sets its `overflow` to `hidden`. To allow your handle to be seen outside of the size of the canvas element, add:

```
.ui-wrapper {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/ceyzbjwd/3/