# Click on an object using canvas and javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I created a canvas with a circle inside it and I'm trying to detect the mouse click.

I am calculating the distance between the mouse click and the radius of the circle. The output should be `0` when the click is next to the center of the circle however I'm getting more than `400`!

Here is the code that I have tried. I couldn't understand what I'm doing wrong!?

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let mousePos = {
  x: undefined,
  y: undefined
};

function Circle(x, y, r) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.r = r;

  this.draw = function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  };

  this.clickCircle = function(xmouse, ymouse) {
    let distance = Math.sqrt(
      (xmouse - this.x) * (xmouse - this.x) +
      (ymouse - this.y) * (ymouse - this.y)
    );
    console.log(distance);
  };
}

let myCircle = new Circle(100, 100, 20);
myCircle.draw();

canvas.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  mousePos.x = e.clientX - rect.left;
  mousePos.y = e.clientY - rect.top;

  myCircle.clickCircle(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: wheat;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <canvas id="app"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: You're stretching the canvas with CSS. That will screw things up. Specify width and height as html attributes. If dynamic resizing is needed, use JS to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, your code is correct except one detail.
Unfortunately, canvas doesn't work with relative sizes (such as %). Actually he does, but that is a style which is applied to the result picture not the canvas itself.

So the only thing you need to change is to remove `width: 100%;` from the CSS code for canvas element and at the same time set the concrete values for canvas width and height via html attributes or by javascript code.

For example:

```
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 300;
...
```

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
// add size. btw, you may calculate those based on the parent element or window
// or just use the values you like
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 300;

let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let mousePos = {
  x: undefined,
  y: undefined
};

function Circle(x, y, r) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.r = r;

  this.draw = function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  };

  this.clickCircle = function(xmouse, ymouse) {
    let distance = Math.sqrt(
      (xmouse - this.x) * (xmouse - this.x) +
      (ymouse - this.y) * (ymouse - this.y)
    );
    console.log(distance);
  };
}

let myCircle = new Circle(100, 100, 20);
myCircle.draw();

canvas.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  mousePos.x = e.clientX - rect.left;
  mousePos.y = e.clientY - rect.top;

  myCircle.clickCircle(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: wheat;
  /* width: 100%; REMOVED THIS */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <canvas id="app"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: yep actually this did work, i didn't know that, however one more question please if i want the canvas to be responsive, do i need to use media query for each resolution or what exactly?

Comment: @walidnaceri you may continuously check the parent or window size and redraw the canvas (with new width and height set), or listen for corresponding events and apply the redraw logic then. Check this answer for better understanding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368477/dynamically-resize-canvas-window-with-javascript-jquery