# mobile full screen html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, canvas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML5 Canvas resize to fit window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664785/html5-canvas-resize-to-fit-window)

I'm developing HTML5 game for mobile phone.

I want to stretch the canvas to take the full phone width and hieght.

I'm using this code but it not very accurate:

```
ourCanvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
context = ourGameCanvas.getContext( '2d' );
ourCanvas.width = $(window).width();
ourCanvas.height = $(window).height();
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your canvas doesn't refresh it's width and height on window resize or orientationchange event:

```
$(window).on("resize", fitCanvas);
fitCanvas();

function fitCanvas() {
    var ourCanvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
    context = ourGameCanvas.getContext( '2d' );
    ourCanvas.width = $(window).width();
    ourCanvas.height = $(window).height();
}
```

Comment: the code is perfect with the PC browsers,BUT there are area on android browsers still not included !!!

Comment: @Solieman If you detect wether or not the orientationchange event is available you can bind eater that or the resize

Comment: There is NO orientationchange,I'm using a browser that prevent it.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649086/detect-rotation-of-android-phone-in-the-browser-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
.outerWidth()
.outerHeight()
```

?

And did you reset your layout? Like:

```
body, html, p, whatever { padding:0; margin:0; }
```