# Javascript set <canvas> to window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, breakout

I am attempting to set a canvas element to the size of the current window.

I did so successfully with jquery here:

```
function windowsize() {
    WIDTH = $("#canvas")[0].width = ($(window).width());
    HEIGHT = $("#canvas")[0].height = ($(window).height());

}

windowsize();
```

I cannot accomplish the same thing in plain javascript, I have as follows:

```
function windowsize(){
    var ctx = document.getElementbyID("canvas");
    ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}
windowsize();
```

Here is a fiddle with the above: http://jsfiddle.net/Kinetic915/bWYy7/

I was also using the following page as a reference:

[Resize HTML5 canvas to fit window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664785/html5-canvas-resize-to-fit-window)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Typo:

```
document.getElementbyID
```

should be:

```
document.getElementById
```

and ctx has no canvas property

Updated Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bWYy7/3/