# My function initCanvas() in JavaScript is drawing the rectangles but not in the correct position

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas, drawing

This is the JavaScript for the canvas element. There must be something wring with the code that fills and draw the rectangles:

```
function initCanvas() {
var ctx = document.getElementById("my_canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
    var mouseX = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
    var mouseY = event.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
    var status = document.getElementById("status");
    status.innerHTML = mouseX + " | " + mouseY;
});

ctx.canvas.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var mouseX = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
    var mouseY = event.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
    //alert(mouseX + " | " + mouseY);
    ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
    ctx.fillRect(mouseX, mouseY, 30, 30);
});
}

window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    initCanvas();
});
```

This is the HTML with the canvas element

```
<body>
    <canvas id="my_canvas"></canvas>
    <h2 id="status">0 | 0</h2>
</body>
```

This is the CSS giving the canvas a height and width

```
canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

h2 {
    color: black;
    font-family: Varela Round;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just setting the `width` and `height` of the canvas in CSS isn't enough to tell the `context` its dimensions. By default the canvas has a `width` of 300 and a `height` of 150. That coordinate system is what's being used when you call `ctx.fillRect` and the reason why it's all stretched out.

What you need is to set your canvas size with JavaScript. Try adding a `resize` listener to the `window` and set the `width` and `height` of the canvas with JavaScript.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);

// call it initially because 'resize' events won't trigger on page load
resizeCanvas();

function resizeCanvas() {
        ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}
```

This will update the context dimension and you're actually drawing based on the window coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the canvas size. Read more at [HTML5 Canvas 100% height and width](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19667859/1447675).

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("my_canvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

But you have to implement a resize event for the actual window size, too.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
});
```

Working example:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("my_canvas");

function initCanvas() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
        var mouseX = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
        var mouseY = event.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
        var status = document.getElementById("status");
        status.innerHTML = mouseX + " | " + mouseY;
    });

    ctx.canvas.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        var mouseX = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
        var mouseY = event.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
        //alert(mouseX + " | " + mouseY);
        ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
        ctx.fillRect(mouseX, mouseY, 30, 30);
    });
}

window.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
    initCanvas();
});

window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
});
```

```css
canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; /* set to % */
}

h2 {
    color: black;
    font-family: Varela Round;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="my_canvas" width="1000" heigth="1000"></canvas>
<h2 id="status">0 | 0</h2>
```

Comment: I'd move the `var canvas = document.getElementById("my_canvas")` outside of the `resize` handler so we're not searching for the element each time we resize. Maybe just declare `var canvas;` at the top. So `initCanvas()` can set the value and the rest of our code can reference it whenever it needs.