# Resize canvas images

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I was wondering how to resize a canvas and all of its drawings as the screen size changes. I know it is 100% possible as this game does (resize your browser and it will fit to any ratio).

http://html5games.com/Game/Smarty-Bubbles/d8f24956-dc91-4902-9096-a46cb1353b6f

Do I have to draw all my shapes with % or multiply them all by a % each time they are drawn? I can appreciate having to redraw on a screen size change but how do I affect the canvas *and* its components?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664785/resize-html5-canvas-to-fit-window

Comment: But what about the objects inside? If a draw a 10x10 square and then increase the window size by 100%, will my square be 20x20? What if I then need to draw another 10x10 square - I would want it to automatically upscale with the new browser size. It must know the window size before it draws itself, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. At the start of the app, save the beginning window width and the beginning canvas size.

   ```
   var originalWindowWidth=window.innerWidth;
   var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
   var originalCanvasWidth=canvas.width;
   var originalCanvasHeight=canvas.height;
   ```
2. Listen for the window resize event
3. Calculate by how much the window width as changed

   ```
   scale=window.innerWidth/originalWindowWidth;
   ```

If your canvas content is complete & unchanging, you can rescale your canvas with CSS. This way you don't have to redraw the canvas content.

4a. (option#1) Scale using CSS:

```
// rescale both CSS width & height by the SAME SCALE FACTOR
$('#canvas').css('width',originalCanvasWidth*scale);
$('#canvas').css('width',originalCanvasWidth*scale);
```

If your canvas content is not complete & unchanging, you should rescale your canvas element itself. This causes all canvas content to be lost so you must redraw it. You can use the `context.scale` command to automatically redraw your content at the new scale factor. Using this method is also less likely to result in pixelated content versus resizing with CSS which "stretches" & "squeezes" existing pixels to fit the new CSS size.

4b. (Option#2) Scale the canvas element itself

```
    var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width=originalCanvasWidth*scale;
    canvas.height=originalCanvasHeight*scale;

    context.scale(scale,scale);

    // now reissue all the drawing commands
    // (no need to adjust coordinates or sizes -- context.scale does that for you!
```

Comment: Now that I have this working, how can I draw a rectangle in the middle of the screen that always takes up the same size of the screen? Do I always need to multiply by a % or base everything off a defaults scale?

Comment: You have several options: (1) Don't do context.scale which means fillrect(x,y,10,10) will draw a rect that's visually 10x10. (2) Do `context.scale` which causes all new drawings to enlarge/shrink by the supplied scaling factor(s) and fillrect(x,y,10,10) will result in a rect that's visually 20x20. If you want a 10x10 square then fillRect(x,y,10/scale,10/scale). The same two options apply to the x,y coordinates. Your original question was "I would want it to automatically upscale with the new browser size" so I added context.scale. If you don't need it you can leave it off and draw normally ;-)

Comment: Thanks. What I did was make a function called myCoordX / myCoordY and they take an input value from 0 - 1 (basically a %) then I multiply it by the width or height of the window. It works perfect but is kinda annoying to have to put every value through it.

Comment: If you find the repeated `*scale` annoying, you could fairly quickly wrap the context drawing commands to automatically adjust for scale: `function myFillRect( x, y, w, h ){ fillRect(x*scale, y*scale, width*scale, height*scale); }`