# relative units in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Is there a way that I can use relative units like vh or vw to draw on the canvas? I tried this:

```
ctx.fillRect('10vh', '10vh', '10vh', '10vh');
```

and even without the quotations but it only works if I use pixels. I need  the shape to resize according to the viewport.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33191909/can-i-specify-canvas-dimensions-using-vh-and-vw

Comment: In addition to Ken Lee's answer, you would need to register an event handler for resize event - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event . Canvas will not resize automatically, you will have to redraw it with newly acquired viewport size information everytime window resize occurs.