# Canvas height and width

Tags: javascript, html, css

When programming in HTML canvas, the js dimensions of the canvas don't always match the css dimensions.
Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you please share some code you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize HTML5 canvas to fit window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664785/resize-html5-canvas-to-fit-window)

Comment: Canvas should not be sized with CSS. It should be sized with HTML attributes of JS dynamically setting of those attributes.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the problem. I was setting the dimensions of the  using CSS, when you actually have to set the width and height attributes. This was causing it to be stretched/skewed.

```
var canvas = $('<canvas/>').attr({width: cw, height: ch}).appendTo('body');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h2yJn/66/

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set the width and height of the canvas to be equal to the dimensions of the window object:

```
function createCanvas() {
    var ctx = //the canvas context;
    ctx.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
    ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
   //your code
}
```

In addition, it is a good idea to set the body and html tags to the full width of the window:

```
body, html{
     height: 100%;
     width:  100%;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can. but that doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by using pure javascript and set the dimensions of the canvas in javascript depending on your CSS values:

```
//Get Canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("canv");

// Get computed style of the canvas element.
var cstyle = window.getComputedStyle(canvas);

// Returns the width as str in px: e.g. 600px.
// Parse resolves that issue.
canv.width = parseInt(cstyle.width);
canv.height = parseInt(cstyle.height);
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/ofaghxfq/2/